# How to center a box on Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm laying out a login screen, and on that screen will be just a box with LOGIN and PASSWORD. I need to centralize vertically and horizontally (like any traditional login screen).

How can I achieve this with Twitter Bootstrap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap grid, then you can offset your columns:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
     Your content goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

See example here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem

Or you can just use CSS to simply center block element,

```
div.login-box{
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 720px;
}
```

Comment: But, Can you achieve responsive behaviour with your second approach?

Comment: You can use simply various CSS media queries to set different width for different resolutions. Or you can experiment with percentage width eg. 70%

Comment: I don't think this answers the question because the first option is an offset (not truly centered), and the second option doesn't use Bootstrap.

Comment: You are being picky here. First answer achieves center position (even when its offset). Second one its plain CSS - provided as an alternative. Bootstrap itself does not offer any class to center block element.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE to Johny's answer: For Bootstrap 3; the syntax is a bit different:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        Your content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

or: better yet:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            Your content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```